# GPU; OpenGL ES 2.0; Read/Write data; NDK; Tegra2;

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Could you show me where I get mistake, please.

Task is very simple. I try to create buffer in GPU memory, write data to one and read from.
Code to do it see below.

When code is executed glCheckFramebufferStatus return value 0x8D40 (constant GL_FRAMEBUFFER in gl2.h) and of course value in out buffer aren't changed.

I can understand what illegal I do and why it doesn't work. May be is necessary use any special flags for compile/link?
Any ideas?!?!?!

Using: Phone Motorola is based on processor Tegra2, libGLES2.so from NVIDIA NDK. Project is compiled by NDK.

Thanks!

```
GLuint xTexID;
GLuint fb;
GLenum status;
const int _wight = 8, _height = 4;

glGenTextures (1, &xTexID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,xTexID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _wight, _height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glGenFramebuffers(1,&fb);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fb);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,xTexID,0);

status = GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE;
if((status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    printf("\r\nmyGL: CheckFramebufferStatus isn't COMPLETE (0x%08X)", status);
//      exit(1);
}

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,_wight,_height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
glReadPixels(0, 0, _wight, _height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any actual drawing calls there.

Up to the glTexSubImage2D call it looks like you're setting up to render to a texture. Once you hit that glTexSubImage2D call what you're trying to do becomes unclear. One would expect there to be a render call somewhere in there in order to fill up the framebuffer you bound. If you haven't rendered to the framebuffer, you won't be seeing any change in the texture you bound to it.